# Im trying something with IF in Batch but is not working as im expecting

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to do an script that looks for some text in a file and also look for a file itself in a %userprofile% path, and it works fine but when i tried to unify it so that instead of outputing 2 confirming messages only output 1, something is not going as expected, this is the code:

```
hostname > hstnm.txt
SET /p hstnm=<hstnm.txt
SET pccer=.filextension1
SET pcsip=.filextension2
SET fullhost=%hstnm%%pccer%
SET fullsip=%hstnm%%pcsip%
SET fullroute=%userprofile%\thepath\%fullhost%
SET siproute=%userprofile%\thepath\%fullsip%

FINDSTR /m "<Protocol>TLS</Protocol>" "%siproute%"
IF %errorlevel%==0 (
 SET siptest="true"
) ELSE (
 SET siptest="false"
)

IF EXIST "%fullroute%" (
 SET certest="true"
) ELSE (
 SET certest="false"
)

IF %siptest%=="true" & %certest%=="true" (
ECHO message if everything good
) ELSE (
ECHO message if something bad
)
pause
```

The FINDSTR and the IF EXIST are working properly (if u swap SET for an ECHO it does display a message). The problem arrives at the part of using the %certest% and the %siproute%, it is doing nothing, just outputs this (if i quit the @echo off)

```
...
C:\path>IF EXIST "C:\Users\Administrador\Appdata\Roaming\Interactive Intelligence\PureCloud Softphone\certificates\sip\GSSES0401107C.grupogss.corp.cer" (SET certest="true" )  ELSE (SET certest="false" )
No se esperaba & en este momento.
C:\path>IF "true"=="true" & "true"=="true" (
C:\path>
```

Help me please! thanks in advance.

Comment: I just entered "help if" in a cmd window. Nothing in the help text showed the use of boolean operators (& in your case). So I guess you'll have to test the first condition in one if first and to use a second if to test the second condition. I'm not a Windows expert though

Comment: and logical AND is usually simulated by `if a==a if b==b echo yep` Also possible in your case: `IF "%siptest%%certest%"=="truetrue"`

Comment: You cannot use `&` like that between  Also double quote both sides of the `if` statement. So here if the 1st matches, it will follow do the next. `IF "%siptest%" == "true" if "%certest%" == "true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sometimes we do not need to do parenthesized `if`'s.
2. There is already a variable containing the hostname called `%COMPUTERNAME%` which you can use without having to create a temp file
3. Pre-set variables and only change them if the files do not exist instead of the `if` `else` statements.
4. nested `if`'s do not use `&`. We simply put the next after the other. `if` one condition returns true, it will do the next, etc. `if` any condition fails, it will stop processing the rest of the line and continue to the next line:

```
@echo off
set "pccer=.filextension1"
set "pcsip=.filextension2"
set "fullhost=%COMPUTERNAME%%pccer%"
set "fullsip=%COMPUTERNAME%%pcsip%"
set "fullroute=%userprofile%\thepath\%fullhost%"
set "siproute=%userprofile%\thepath\%fullsip%"
set "siptest=false"
set "certest=false"

FINDSTR /m "<Protocol>TLS</Protocol>" "%siproute%"
if not errorlevel 1 set "siptest=true"
if exist "%fullroute%" set "certest=true"

if "%siptest%" == "true" if "%certest%" == "true" echo message if everything good & goto :done
echo message if something bad

:done
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The line in question has a '&' character which I assume you are trying to use as a boolean AND operator - 'IF' in CMD **does not have an AND operator**.  The CMD command chain mechanism does and that's where the probably confusion arises.  I typically nest IFs in cases like this:

```
IF %siptest%=="true" (  
    IF %certest%=="true" (...
```

The '&' operator " simply chains a number of command together on one line:

```
dir & cd \ & dir & del myfile.txt
```

**All** the above command will be executed, one after the other.

On the other hand, the '&&' operator works a bit more like an AND operator in that it executes the next command in the chain only if ERRORLEVEL of the previous command is "0" (no error).

```
del myfile.txt && echo Done! && cd c:\
```

The echo command will only be executed if del command returns a 0 as its ERRORLEVEL.  The cd command is dependent on the results **all of the previous commands**, meaning it only takes one failed command to break the chain.

I am personally also careful how I use variables and **always** enclose them:

```
IF "%MYVAR%"=="0" (...
```

I do that because in the end you are not comparing a variable to something, but rather it is a simple string comparison; CMD variables are replaced with the content of what they represent **before** any actions on them.  When that replacement happens can be adjusted to a certain degree, but in the end it is always a string comparison.  That means that if the variable doesn't have any content (it happens) and you use that to compare, without some kind of enclosure, then your script will fail and exit, due to the resulting IF being malformed.

https://ss64.com/nt/if.html
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: Your right.  I often go on tangents.  :-/
I originally had included both "exit code" and ERRORLEVEL, but removed it.  Dunno why.
You are also correct with number operators, however I thought it more important to emphasize the variable to string replacement as that happens before CMD determines if the comparison should be numeric in nature.